# How to achieve menu animation in android

Tags: android, ios, animation, scroll, slide

I want to achieve a animated scrolling menu options in ANDROID like the following functionality in iOS

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NkuChdWA_I

I have try to do it by onScrollUp and onScrollDown listview, but unable to find the desire result.

```
private class ParallaxStikkyAnimator extends HeaderStikkyAnimator {
@Override
public AnimatorBuilder getAnimatorBuilder() {
    mHeader_image = getHeader().findViewById(R.id.ll_boxeshorizntal);
    return AnimatorBuilder.create().applyVerticalParallax(mHeader_image);
}
@Override
public void onScroll(final int scrolledY) {
    super.onScroll(scrolledY);
    listview.setOnDetectScrollListener(new OnDetectScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUpScrolling() {
           // ll_boxes.setAlpha(1.0f);
            Log.e("onUpScrolling", "Up scrolledY==" + scrolledY);
          //  slideToTop(mHeader_image, scrolledY);
          if (scrolledY == 0) {

             /* ll_four_boxes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              ll_boxeshorizntal.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDownScrolling() {
            Log.e("onDownScrolling", "scrolledY==" + scrolledY);
              //  slideToBottom(mHeader_image, scrolledY);
           // slideToBottom(mHeader_image, scrolledY);
            DownScrolling(scrolledY);
            if (scrolledY < 300) {

               /* ll_four_boxes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ll_boxeshorizntal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

I can use the two view for Gone and Visible according to the scroll but how to achieve animation like iOS.

Basically i have to convert a GridView with Two row and Two column to One Row and Four Column with animation.

Comment: Where have you started? Where is your code that tries to achieve the expected behaviour and doesn't work?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: You can make a view visible or hide on the basis of the value of scrolledY. If it is more than say some value then hide one view and display the other one.

Comment: Yes. But how to animate these view @gRaWEty

Answer (score 0):

You can check how much scrolling is done by using [scrollView.getScrollY()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollY). And on the basis of the value make the buttons visible or hide or change their width accordingly so that you can fit four buttons in a single row and when it is at top then display 2 buttons per row.